# Did the Romans give names to instances of natural disasters?

Tags: classical-latin, history, roman-culture, names, nature

It is common to name storms.
For example, a hurricane called Harvey is now over Texas.
On the other hand, ancient people named deities related to various places and natural phenomena.
There might be a deity for a specific river or for a specific kind of wind.

But did the Romans ever give a name to a specific event in a fashion similar to how we name storms?
I don't recall hearing of "one-shot deities" that were related to a specific instance of a natural disaster (eg. a single storm) instead of the phenomenon in general (eg. a god of storms).
Were natural disasters described through the related gods or deities at all, even if the specific event was not given a separate name?

Comment: There is a wikipedia article about that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone_naming#History

Comment: @Luc Good find! That indicates that the naming scheme we use today is far too young. If there was an older analogous thing further back in history, I would assume it to be mentioned. The remaining question is whether the Romans gave any names for their natural disasters. Since it is hard to prove negatives, a "I've never seen it so it probably doesn't exist" would make a valid answer, especially together with that bit of history you linked to.

Comment: Indeed :) However, before starting to search, I was pretty convinced this wasn’t that old, so this result can be biased. By the way, it was a lot older than I thought.